# Is additive group of complex numbers indecomposable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Recall that a group $G$ is called indecomposable if it cannot be written as a direct sum of two proper normal subgroups.

My Question is "Is additive group of complex numbers indecomposable?

I stuck in proving this. I searched it a lot more on internet. But, I could not find any thing regarding this Question. Please give a short proof or a relevant source where I can find its solution. I will be highly thankful to you.

Comment: Indecomposable in what sense?

Comment: Now, I have added the definition of indecomposable group.  Thank You for pointing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean decomposable into a direct product, then it is:
it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +) \times (\mathbb{R}, +)$.